# Save each line as separate .txt file using Notepad++

Tags: python, notepad++

I am using Notepad++ to restructure some data.  Each .txt file has 99 lines.  I am trying to run a python script to create 99 single-line files.

Here is the .py script I am currently running, which I found in a previous thread on the topic.  I'm not sure why, but it isn't quite doing the job:

```
    yourfile = open('filename.TXT', 'r')
    counter = 0
    magic = yourfile.readlines()

    for i in magic:
        counter += 1
        newfile = open(('filename_' + str(counter) + '.TXT'), "w")
        newfile.write(i)
        newfile.close()
```

When I run this particular script, it simply creates a copy of the host file, and it still has 99 lines.

Comment: Add a `print(len(magic))` in that gap...what's it say? It sounds like `.readlines()` is thinking there's only one line. How are the lines in your file delimited?

Comment: There is no line delimiter in these txt files, they are simply linebreaks.

Comment: The answers below (other than omitting 99 from the call to `.readlines()` which you originally had then removed) should all function identically to your code. If they all of a sudden work, I think the description of your problem is incomplete. "Creating a copy of the host file" makes it sound like there's only one element in `magic`.

Comment: If there are no line breaks \n in the file then it might be the case.

Comment: I'm not sure what information is missing.  

Each text file contains 99 lines of chat dialogue.  There are no delimiters.  I took a script from another topic and tried to apply the logic here.  I do not know Python.  I used Python 2.6 msi, since it is compatible with Notepad++, to execute my .py file in the same folder as the .txt file.  The result is a renamed but identical file to what I started with.  I do not know where this train fell off the rails.

Comment: New filename still has counter set to 0.  Looks like 1-99 never gets generated.

Is there a character limit on readlines?  My text strings on each line are from chat dialogues, and are quite long.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change the structure of your script a bit:

```
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        with open('filename_{}.txt'.format(i), 'w') as wf:
            wf.write(line)
```

In this format you have the benefit of relying on context managers to close your file handler and also you don't have to read things separately, there isa better logical flow.

Comment: Better still:  `for i, line in enumerate(f):`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following piece of code to achieve that. It's commented, but feel free to ask.

```
#reading info from infile with 99 lines
infile = 'filename.txt'

#using context handler to open infile and readlines
with open(infile, 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

#initializing counter
counter = 0

#for each line, create a new file and write line to it.
for line in lines:

    #define outfile name
    outfile = 'filename_' + str(counter) + '.txt'

    #create outfile and write line
    with open(outfile, 'w') as g:
        g.write(line)

    #add +1 to counter
    counter += 1
```

Comment: Never write inane comments like "add +1 to counter".

Answer (score 0):

```
magic = yourfile.readlines(99)
```

Please try remove '99' like this.

```
magic = yourfile.readlines()
```

I tried it and I have 99 file that have a single line each one.